# Is there a way to find out why a python program closed?

Tags: python, file-io

Is there a way to programmatically find out *why* a **Python** program closed?

I'm making a game in python, and I've been using the built in **open()** function to create a log in a .txt file. A major problem I've come across is that when it occasionally crashes, the log doesn't realise it's crashed.
 I've managed to record if the user closes the game through pressing an exit button, but I was wondering if there is a way to check *how* the program closed. For instance if the user presses exit, if it crashes or if it is forcefully closed(through the task manager for instance)

Comment: Have a look at the [signal](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/signal.html#module-signal)-module. You should be able to trap the most common...

Answer (score 5):

You can supply your own exception handler:

```
import sys, logging
def excepthook_logger(extype, value, traceback):
    logging.exception("Oh no! An uncaught exception happened!")
    # Uncomment to also show the exceptions
    #sys.__excepthook__(extype, value, traceback)
sys.excepthook = excepthook_logger
```

Then every uncaught exception is logged in your log file.

Answer (score 2):

A few tips:

- use try catch wherever possible.
- Even if it crashes, stack trace will tell which line was last executed.

Comment: But how can I get the information from stack trace to appear in the .txt file? Is there a way to convert that information in to a string? I dont entirely understand what stack trace is D:

Comment: usually the last line of stack trace will show you where you did wrong in your code. If you want stack trace in .txt file, you can append it in a file(using '>').

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the Python debugger that is installed by defaut 
In commandline for example you can inspect your programm

> > >>>import pdb
> >
> > >>>import youprogram.py

and then test it by typing

> > >>>yourprogramm.test()
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in ?
>
> File "./mymodule.py", line 4, in test
>
> test2()
>
> File "./mymodule.py", line 3, in test2
>
> print spam

To have a closer look you should consider setting debug trace to stop the execution at critical points using

> pdb.set_trace()

that stop the execution commenting the current action

For more details I recommend you to see the documentation page
http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html